# Wcf Throttling and InstanceContextMode.PerSession behaviour

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I'm quite misunderstanding the InstanceContextMode.PerSession behavior.

I know about if we want to connect the client with dedicated session, which mean when a client connect the service a session will hold all its calls till the client close the connection.

So is this scenario what is the PerSession behaviour mean or something else.

and in the Throttling we have the MaxConcurrentSessions .

My question : If we declare the InstanceContextMode with PerCall does is the same mean of session dedicated for each client and how the MaxConcurrentSessions  affects the PerCall behaviour .

Answer (score 0):

Per call means that for each call a new instance of the service is created to process the call. So there is no possibility of session state being maintained between calls. I suspect that the throttling setting has no effect in this case.

Comment: MaxConcurrentInstances throttling would still apply.